# How to use PropertyUtils to get an element from a list inside a map?

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils, indexed-properties

I've been trying to use the indexed notation used for getProperty of PropertyUtils to retrieve an element in a list contained as a map value. Here's an example (I'm using a general syntax here):

```
map = {"aList": ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"]}
```

Let say, I want to get the value "elem2", I'm trying to do it using:

```
PropertyUtils.getProperty(map, "aList[1]");
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I always get a null value. Is there another way to do this. To be clear, I know I can do a `getProperty("aList").get(0)` (after explicitly casting, of course) but I'm working on a solution that needs the code stated above to work.

Comment: I've figured this out already. Will post the answer later since the rules won't allow me to answer within 8 hours of posting the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. The code below works like how I wanted:

```
PropertyUtils.getProperty(map, "(aList)[1]");
```

I think, based on [this documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.html), what I'm doing here is that I'm specifying that `aList` is a key and not an indexed property of the bean. Something like that.

Comment: For anyone who came across this looking for how to get a value from Map of Maps of Maps of Maps etc (e.g. objectified JSON): PropertyUtils.getProperty(map, "(keyInFirstMap).(keyInSecondMap).(keyInThirdMap)"); A possible warning though: Apache's BeanUtils performance can be bad (see http://rodrigojramirez.com/2013/10/21/beware-of-copyproperties-or-the-30-milliseconds-tale/) - after experiencing it first hand, I'd run a test before using PropertyUtils like above on a heavily exercised code path.